# How to create a schema for any TypeScript type using zod?

Tags: typescript, zod

How to extend zod's typing with an external interface/type. I tried using `z.custom<>` but couldn't get the expected result.

The type here doesn't matter, because it's any, I want to get this type and use it in the zod.

```
import * as z from 'zod'

import { MyType } from '.myType'

const mySchema = z.object({
  custom: z.custom<MyType>()
})
```

Comment: Do you need it to *have validation*? (plz ping @Dimava so I see the message)

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states: [If you don't provide a validation function, Zod will allow any value. This can be dangerous!](https://zod.dev/?id=custom-schemas)

The usual/recommended Zod approach is to create your schema as `const MyType = z./* [...] */` and then extract the type as `type MyType = z.infer<typeof MyType>;`.

If you want to go the other way around (which for many people makes more sense, as it's a looser coupling) there are things like [`ts-to-zod`](https://github.com/fabien0102/ts-to-zod) that automatically create schemas for your interfaces and types.